# CSS content counter for nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a counter in my nav bar but only for selected items. I don't want the counter to display for sub-menu items, only for the main nav headings(Home, Commissions, Personal, Info, Contact).
Right now when the counter hovers over a sub-menu item, the counter is on top of my li headings.

I've placed numbers for where some headings will be as the client hasn't decided what to put there yet.

I'm fairly new to coding and still trying to grasp the concept of :before and :after.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #f4f3ee;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #010101;
  counter-reset: counter;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 15vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}


.nav-bar ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  counter-increment: counter;
  content: "0" counter(counter);
  transform: translateY(7px);
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out, transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.nav-bar ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-out;
}

.nav-bar ul li span:after {
  content: "";
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-out;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 104px;
  margin-top: -23px;
}

a,
span.a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-bar li:hover .nav-links {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="a">Commissions</span>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="a">Personal</span>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="a">Info</span>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using the normal list numbers. `ol {
    padding: 20px; 
    list-style-type: decimal;

}
ol li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}`

Comment: Use `<ol>` instead of `<ul>` with the CSS above. Apply class to dropdown items where you do not want to display the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need. Somehow you need to select only the "top-level" elements but since your structure does not allow it, I added the `a` class on the top level elements to target them.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #f4f3ee;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #010101;
  counter-reset: counter;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 15vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.a:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  counter-increment: counter;
  content: "0" counter(counter);
  transform: translateY(3px);
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out, transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.nav-bar ul li:before {
  
}

.nav-bar ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-out;
}

.nav-bar ul li span:after {
  content: "";
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-out;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 104px;
  margin-top: -23px;
}

a,
span.a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-bar li:hover .nav-links {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="a" href="">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="a">Commissions</span>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="a">Personal</span>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="a">Info</span>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a class="a" href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```